# How to make clock stop

Tags: javascript

I have to create two methods start and stop. Start method starts displaying current time in console in format ‘hh:mm:ss’ every second starting from now. Second method stops it.
I am using clearInterval() to stop it but which argument should I pass there?

```
class Clock {

  constructor(){
    this.date = new Date()
    this.hours = this.date.getHours()
    this.minutes = this.date.getMinutes()
    this.seconds = this.date.getSeconds()
  }

  run(){
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.seconds+= 1
      if (this.seconds >= 60){
        this.minutes++
        this.seconds= 0
      }
      if (this.minutes >= 60){
        this.hours++
        this.minutes=0
      }
      if (this.hours >= 24){
        this.hours = 0
      }
      console.log(`${this.hours}:${this.minutes}:${this.seconds}`)
    }, 1000)
  }

  stop(){
    return clearInterval()
  }

}
```

Comment: The value that is returned by `setInterval`.

Comment: `setInterval()` returns an id that should be passed to `clearInterval()` to clear a particular interval. First save the interval id: `this.intervalID = setInterval(...);`. Then inside the `stop()` method, pass `this.intervalID` to `clearInterval()` --> `clearInterval(this.intervalID)`

Comment: I was trying like this but then I was getting in my tests: Expected: "00:00:00" Received: -> 1: "6:39:30" 2: "6:39:31"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `run` method, assign the number returned by `setInterval` to an attribute:

```js
run(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => { ... });
}
```

Later, in your `stop` method, pass that attribute to the `clearInterval` fn invocation:

```js
stop(){
  return clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

That's how it will know which interval you want to clear.

Comment: I was trying like this but I am getting in my tests:
    Expected: "00:00:00"
    Received:
    ->     1: "6:39:30"
            2: "6:39:31"

Comment: Can you describe your test case?

Comment: I added the test in description.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the line `expect(console.log).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, '00:00:00');` that's failing for you. It looks like your clock's time is 6:39:30—probably because you set it to the current date and time.

If you want your test to pass, I think you need to initialize your clock to 00:00:00 first. And then you also need to make sure you log *before* incrementing the seconds counter, otherwise it will at the very least log 00:00:01.